# Microsoft Azure Service Bus / Hybrid Connection

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I am looking for a solution to solve the below...

I have a SQL db in an on premise server that runs on a LAN locked down to our site only.

I also have a server up on the cloud with a SQL database.

I need to create a process that grabs data from the cloud and inserts it into the on premise server.

So I'm thinking the below...

- Create an Azure web app
- Create a hybrid connection in above web app to connect to on premise
- Create service bus in azure to facilitate the above.

The web app will just be a script in c# pushing data from one place to the other.

What do you think? Is this feasible? Also need it to be cost effective.

Comment: Why not pull data with a console app/service from on-prem?

Comment: @evilSnobu do you mean just run a new server on premise and install a new app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Data Sync to keep your on-premise SQL and your Azure SQL Database synchronized, this way you don't need to create an Azure Web App and you don't need to use Service Bus. The synchronization can be set bi-directional or on one direction (cloud to on-premise). To get started with Azure SQL Data Sync please follow instructions on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that, looked into it and whilst it does achieve the data sync aspect what concerns me is the 'preview' status, I'd be reluctant to deploy something that is in beta/preview, presumably if azure get poor feedback in this preview stage they could discontinue that feature

Comment: A few months ago I helped a retail customer in Mexico synch 72 retail stores with SQL Azure. They now have each SQL Server instance installed on their stores in synch with SQL Azure. What you need to take inconsideration the most is that schema changes need to be replicated manually.

Comment: Despite being in preview I cannot imagine seen Azure SQL Database without SQL Data Sync. Many customers rely on it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, what do you think about this idea, I spoke to our cloud host and asked them if they could create us a new server and lock it down securely so it can only speak to our internal on premise server but speak to the SQL db on that server. They said it was absolutely possible as long as my on premise db allows remote connections, what do you think?

Comment: You can create a firewall rule with the IP associated of your company. You can set access from Azure service Off also. You may also consider Virtual Network rules https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview